# An emptyView for loading data and another for when there is no data available

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a case of using a CarouselView that is displayed based on certain data brought from an API, the point is that I need to see a certain view or at least text while the API data is being downloaded and another one in case That there is no data.
I tried to get to this using RefreshView and EmptyView but I cannot achieve the required behavior, I can make an EmptyView appear immediately the data begins to load since at that moment the ItemSource is null, then when the data reaches the app the Carousel appears , which seems to me quite ugly, the ideal would be to show some view that next to the RefreshView indicator shows that the data is loading and then in case of not bringing any data show a view that of the feedback that API data did not return .

I hope I have made myself understood and I hope someone can give me an idea on how to achieve this behavior.

MyViewModel:

```
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;
        Things = new ObservableCollection<Things>();
        var t = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await LoadThings();


        });
        Task.WhenAll(t);
        IsRefreshing = false;

    }



    private async Task LoadThings()
    {
        Things = new List<Thing>(await App.WebApiManager.GetThingsAsync(Id));
    }
```

My IsRefreshing property is linked to the IsRefreshing property in the RefreshView that encompasses my CarouselView

Comment: How did you define your ViewModel, more specifically the property you are binding to the `ItemSource` of the `CarouselView` could you show the code. By reading your post I could say that a "fix" could be initializing the collection, so it is not null but empty then assigning the values once they return from the Api. If you show the code of your VM we could understand better your case.

Comment: In my case, I used a progress bar at the top while the api is fetching data. Another would be using a popup view with loading animation in it. After fetching, you could bind the isVisible property of a text or any view component you want whenever the ItemSource.count == 0

Comment: @pinedax I edited the question with the mMyViewModel codel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use two empty view and switch between them when the refreshing status changes, and here is the code:

add two content view in in XAML and set default empty view to LoadingData:

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ContentView x:Key="LoadingData">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Loading data..."
                       Margin="10,25,10,10"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       FontSize="18"
                       HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>
        <ContentView x:Key="NoDataLoaded">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="No items to display."
                       Margin="10,25,10,10"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       FontSize="18"
                       HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentView>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                     Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
            <CarouselView x:Name="carouselView"
                          EmptyView="{StaticResource LoadingData}">
               ... ...
```

and in code, show different empty view accordingly:

```
public partial class HorizontalPullToRefreshPage : ContentPage
    {
        AnimalsViewModel viewModel;
        public HorizontalPullToRefreshPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = new AnimalsViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = viewModel;
            viewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;
        }

        private void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName.Equals("IsRefreshing"))
            {
                if (viewModel.IsRefreshing && viewModel.Animals.Count==0)
                {
                    carouselView.EmptyView = Resources["LoadingData"];
                }
                else if (!viewModel.IsRefreshing && viewModel.Animals.Count == 0)
                {
                    carouselView.EmptyView = Resources["NoDataLoaded"];
                }
            }
        }            

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            await Task.Delay(2000);
            carouselView.ItemsSource = viewModel.Animals;
        }
    }
```

then, every time the property IsRefreshing changed, you got a chance to switch the empty view.

Hope it helps.